# Illustrator Artwork, from only one of our artists, is extremely slow to work with

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I work for a company that mainly sells city and state art transfer-printed, etched, engraved, etc. onto dinnerware.

Most of the time i deal with the art, personally, i see that it contains anywhere from 15,000-30,000 paths but have no problems working with them quickly . However, one of our artist's illustrations always has a tremendous amount of paths in the 150,000-250,000 range...and i wanted to see if there was anything i could do.

**What I have tried**

1. Fix bad plug-in global object names(no idea what this meant, just
   saw it [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/kb/copy-paste-artwork-slow-or.html)
2. Object>Path>simplify (made sure to not include text outlines. Has
   never worked in a year's worth of attempts.)
3. Object>Path>Clean up : says it isn't needed.

Image below is of Sixteen pieces of artwork for a square dinner plate. **[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wiay5c3a135vxyu/atlanta-exampleart-forGDSE.ai?dl=0) is a link to a single piece of artwork from that product, so you can take a look and *hopefully* help me out.**

**Do you see anything i can correct in the file supplied?** [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple steps for that file... although that file isn't problematic here.

First fix the type counters on the arch by filling them with white. Then . . .

- Select All
- `Object > Expand`
- Pathfinder Panel > Merge
- Click a white filled object (with the Direct Select Tool - white arrow)
- `Select > Same > Fill & Stroke`
- Hit <kbd>Delete</kbd>
- Draw a no fill, no stroke rectangle
- `Select > Same > Fill & Stroke`
- Hit <kbd>Delete</kbd>

This removes at least 50% of the objects in the file.

Comment: Scott, you're my hero. I just did this to the artwork for one of our Cape Cod products. Started with 240,000 paths, down to 159,000. I can confirm this one was an example of a source file we lost and had to have it retraced from a raster..so it makes sense to still have a LOT of paths...but this was a HUGE difference in terms of rendering performance. You're the man scott...THE MAN.

Comment: I'm glad that helped, @orbitalshocK

Answer (score 0):

If it's for the cause of simplifying paths, I find Inkscape does a much better job then Illustrator. You would need to export it to svg from Illustrotor, import it into inkscape and I suggest you try it one path first: select it and hit CTRL+L. It will tell how many 'nodes' it found and how many are left after simplifying. (Or you can use the menu: Path --> Simplify)